# How to start a remote kernel on a machine with two ip addresses?

Tags: remote-access

Suppose I have a local machine with ip address 204.XX.40.10 and a remote machine.
And the remote machine has two network card, so it has two ip addresses: 204.XX.40.21 and 192.0.2.100, and only the 204.XX.40.21 one can be reached from outside.

I tried the [guide](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12495) in the documentation but I can't get the remote kernel working.

It turns out that the main link is successfully connected but the other links are listening at the private ip address 192.0.2.100 on the remote machine. Here are information I get after login to the remote machine.

```
[user@remote ~]$ lsof -i 4 -a
COMMAND     PID USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
MathKerne 71149 user   16u  IPv4 4045791      0t0  TCP remote:43021->204.XX.40.10:54201 (ESTABLISHED)
MathKerne 71149 user   17u  IPv4 4045790      0t0  TCP remote:34952->204.XX.40.10:54200 (ESTABLISHED)
MathKerne 71149 user   20u  IPv4 4045795      0t0  TCP 192.0.2.100:55230 (LISTEN)
MathKerne 71149 user   21u  IPv4 4045797      0t0  TCP 192.0.2.100:49758 (LISTEN)
MathKerne 71149 user   22u  IPv4 4045800      0t0  TCP 192.0.2.100:59492 (LISTEN)
MathKerne 71149 user   23u  IPv4 4045802      0t0  TCP 192.0.2.100:48302 (LISTEN)
```

So is it possible to let the other two links using the public ip address?